# Named query doesn't like regex

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a query in my code that looks like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "foo", query = "SELECT x from Y y WHERE y.a = :b AND y.c = :d AND e = 'Y' ORDER BY y.f DESC");
```

This compiles fine and gives correct results, but I wanted to perform a case insensitive match, so I changed this in this way:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "foo", query = "SELECT x from Y y WHERE regexp_like(y.a, '^:b$', 'i') AND y.c = :d AND e = 'Y' ORDER BY y.f DESC");
```

Now, this does not compile.  I get the following error:

```
2023-10-16 11:13:33,202 ERROR [main] o.h.h.PARSER - <AST>:1:105: unexpected AST node: (
```

It appears that the '(' in the after 'regexp_like' is causing a compile issue, I don't see why this should be since you need to put in an open bracket after calling 'regexp_like'.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Bind variable is a **data**, not a substitution value for some part of SQL text. You have to concatenate `'^'` with passed parameter to obtain combined pattern

Comment: Even if I remove '^' and '$', I get the same issue.

Comment: The linked duplicate is for Oracle DB, but should apply to other engines as well.

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.